# Ordering and renaming Columns in Pandas data frame - Elegant Solution Possible?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string, list

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
   df 
        ATG@FTY@RG@NUMFB@ZQ=CT    QTG@SSTY@RG@NUMFB@ZQ=ED   WQTG@SSTWY@RGW@NUMFB@ZQ=XED QQTG@SSTQY@RGQ@NUMFB@ZQ=XXED
                   1                            2                      3                         4
                   2                            4                      6                         2
                   1                            0                      3                         7
```

What I am looking for is to create a duplicate of the existing data frame but by reordering the names split by '@' and '=' and dropping the keyword 'ZQ' and adding 'Z' at the end. So for example the 1st column name from

```
      **ATG@FTY@RG@NUMFB@ZQ=CT **  should transform to ** ATG@FTY@RG@CT@NUMFBZ**  ( with a 'Z appended at end say)
```

So I created the following code which works fine. **However looking at a more elegant pythonic solution**

```
 import pandas as pd
 import re
    
 for col in dfT.columns:
    zl=[] 
    fl = []
    mc=col.split('@')
    myL =mc[:-2]

    nfS =mc[-2]

    fnf =nfS+'Z'
    fl.append(fnf)

    zn = mc[-1].split('=')
    zl = list(zn)
    zl.remove('ZQ')

    myL.extend(zl)
    myL.extend(fl)
    mst ='@'.join(myL)

    dfT.rename(columns = {col:mst}, inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
In [80]: columns
Out[80]:
['ATG@FTY@RG@NUMFB@ZQ=CT',
 'QTG@SSTY@RG@NUMFB@ZQ=ED',
 'WQTG@SSTWY@RGW@NUMFB@ZQ=XED',
 'QQTG@SSTQY@RGQ@NUMFB@ZQ=XXED']

In [81]: def renamer(col):
    ...:     a,b,c = col.rsplit('@', 2)
    ...:     return f"{a}@{c.split('=')[1]}@{b}Z"
    ...:

In [82]: renamed = dict(zip(columns, map(renamer, columns)))

In [83]: renamed
Out[83]:
{'ATG@FTY@RG@NUMFB@ZQ=CT': 'ATG@FTY@RG@CT@NUMFBZ',
 'QTG@SSTY@RG@NUMFB@ZQ=ED': 'QTG@SSTY@RG@ED@NUMFBZ',
 'WQTG@SSTWY@RGW@NUMFB@ZQ=XED': 'WQTG@SSTWY@RGW@XED@NUMFBZ',
 'QQTG@SSTQY@RGQ@NUMFB@ZQ=XXED': 'QQTG@SSTQY@RGQ@XXED@NUMFBZ'}
```

you can use `renamed` in your `df.rename` call directly

Answer (score 0):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('@NUMFB@ZQ=', '@') + '@NUMFBZ'

# Index(['ATG@FTY@RG@CT@NUMFBZ', 'QTG@SSTY@RG@ED@NUMFBZ',
#        'WQTG@SSTWY@RGW@XED@NUMFBZ', 'QQTG@SSTQY@RGQ@XXED@NUMFBZ'],
```

Comment: code only answers are not recommended. Can you please explain this code for OP and for future SO members that may want to understand what your answer meant.